# Variable enclosed with "<" and ">"

Tags: ios, objective-c

In the Google Analytics iOS [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/53459/google-analytics-ios) there is the following line:

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
```

Why is the `GAITracker` variable enclosed with "<" and ">"? Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linuxios explained what the syntax means.  I'll try to explain the why...

When you write a `@Protocol`, you define a number of required and optional methods for which objects conforming to the protocol may implement.

Suppose I have a `@Protocol` that looks like this:

```
@Protocol FooProtocol
@required
- (void)doStuff;
@End
```

So now, every thing that conforms to `<FooProtocol>` has to implement a method called `doStuff`.

So, if I do this:

```
NSObject *bar = [[Bar alloc] init];
```

If I try doing this:

```
[bar doStuff];
```

Xcode will tell me that `NSObject` has no visible selector "doStuff".

However, if I change my code to this:

```
NSObject<FooProtocol> *bar = [[Bar alloc] init];
```

Now Xcode will be fine with:

```
[bar doStuff];
```

Because although `NSObject` still has no visible selector, "doStuff", the `FooProtocol`, which I've implemented does have a selector called "doStuff", and `bar` isn't just an NSObject, but specifically, it's an NSObject that conforms to the `FooProtocol`.

---

Now, in this explanation it's a bit of a silly case.  But it's particularly helpful when you want a `UIViewController`, for example, to act as a `TextFieldDelegate`.  A regular `UIViewController` can't do this.

However, a `UIViewController<TextFieldDelegate>` can perform this duty because it's not just a `UIViewController`, but it's a `UIViewController` that conforms to the `TextFieldDelegate` protocol.

Answer (score 4):

That means that you have a variable of type `id` (any object), but only ones that conform to the GAITracker protocol.

The general syntax is this:

```
type<protocol1,protocol2> varname
```

This specifies a variable of type `type` that can only hold objects that conform to all the protocols in the list between brackets.